# Italic Fonts in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, tcpdf

First of all, sorry I am really new to fonts, I don't know much about them. I am using a font called "oswald" ([link](http://www.google.com/webfonts/specimen/Oswald#charset)) inside TCPDF. I am using a project that a developer before me has made so I'm not sure if this font came integrated with TCPDF or if it was imported into it.

I am trying to make it italic, but I'm having no luck, the text is being displayed as normal. Inside my fonts directory, I can see the "oswald" files:

```
oswald.php 
oswald.ctg.z    
oswald.z
```

I have used the TCPDF ability SetFont ([Link to Doc](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#afd56e360c43553830d543323e81bc045)) and set the "style" to italic. I can confirm that the setting of the style works, because when I "getFontStyle" it returns an "i" for italic. When I open up oswald.php I can see this code:

```
$desc=array('Ascent'=>1184,'Descent'=>-309,'CapHeight'=>11,'Flags'=>32,'FontBBox'=>'[-103 -309 1346 1184]','ItalicAngle'=>30,'StemV'=>70,'MissingWidth'=>600);
```

Before, ItalicAngle was 0, so I tried changing it to 30, thinking that perhaps it would make it angle 30 degrees? But it didn't effect anything.

**Questions**

1. Does changing this array inside the code change anything about how the font is rendered?
2. Do I need to recreate the "ctg.z" and "z" files using the php as a source file?
3. Does this particular font not even support an italic mode?